# Rename a file if it exists powershell

Tags: powershell, backup

I have a script that will backup files from 100 days ago and will backup 5 days worth of files for the original backup. Then I will need to run the script everyday to backup any new files generated. I am trying to see if any file exists and if it does then rename it with a timestamp. I am not sure if I am going about this the right way. Is there anything I can do to make my script better?? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function BackupArtifacts {

Param(
$SourceFile,
$Destination,
$StartRange,
$NumberOfDaysCopied
)

$NewFileName = $FileName_ + $TimeStamp

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Destination
$count = 0

foreach ($fileList in Get-ChildItem $SourceFile -recurse) 
{    
    if ($fileList.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays($StartRange) -and $fileList.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($StartRange + $NumberOfDaysCopied)) #Go back 100 days and copy 5 days worth of files
    { 
        #Check if file already exists and if it does then rename it 
        If (Test-Path ($Destination, $NewFileName) -join "")
        {
            While (Test-Path @($Destination, $NewFileName) -join "") 
            {
                $NewFileName = "$NewFileName_ + $TimeStamp"
            }
            Rename-Item -Path ( ($Destination) -join '') -NewName ($NewFileName)
        }             
        try {
             #Copy-Item $fileList.FullName -Destination $Destination -Recurse
             Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination (@($Destination,$NewFileName) -join "") -Force
             Write-Host $fileList.FullName
             $count ++                                
        } catch {
        Write-Error $_
        }
     }                            
}
Write-Host "Backup complete, Number of files backed up:" $count
}

$SourceFile = "C:\TempCopy"
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy
$Destination = "C:\TempCopyBackUp_" + $TimeStamp
$StartRange = "-100"
$NumberOfDaysCopied = "5"

BackupArtifacts $SourceFile $Destination $StartRange $NumberOfDaysCopied
```

Comment: If your code is working but you'd live a review, please post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - if it's _not working_, please be specific about what isn't working :)

Comment: Sorry no it is not working. It creates a copy folder but it does not copy any files, its just an empty folder. I think there is something wrong in my Copy-Item command but not sure what?? @MathiasR.Jessen